# get the image which is already been downloaded and cached using glide library

Tags: android

I am using glide library to download and cache the images. on click of Imageview I need to pass the downloaded image from this to next activity. In the next activity I have an another Imageview which will display the image that was coming the current activity. So, how to get the cached image. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass image url throgh Intent like;

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("url", url);
 startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
id= i.getStringExtra("image_url");

**When I need to show cached image, I use the same url and**
```

`DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE:`

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass image url throgh Intent like;

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("image_url", image_url);
 startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
id= i.getStringExtra("image_url");
```

set url to ImageView using Glide;

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(Uri.parse(id))
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: @thanks for your kind response. I tried with passing image url. it is not taking the cache image. instead, it download the image from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Glide doesn't support directly accessing the cache by design. Cache is a transparent storage, meaning you don't need to know about it. Also in Glide the caching is much more fine grained than just the url as key, see `EngineKey`.

So the solution is to load normally and it will be loaded from the cache if it's there, otherwise downloaded and then loaded. Look into `.diskCacheStrategy()` for more control as to what gets cached.

Is this offline mode? If so check out the comments in [Ensuring That Images Loaded Only Come From Disk Cache](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glidelibrary/TcFOy0tcxXA) on 12 June 2015

For other use cases see the network of related issues [Check here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/459) .